# Laravel 6x Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am fairly new to Laravel.  I've been looking into Middleware and how to implement this and based on the docs.

I have a route passing through my IsAdmin Middleware Class.

For some reason when the user IsAdmin is set to 0 it's still completing the request.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class IsAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

     $IfAdmin = auth()->user()->IsAdmin;

      if (!auth()->user()->IsAdmin = "1"){

     abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');

      }else{

        return $next($request);
        }

    }
}
```

In my DB for the user table "IsAdmin" is set to 0.  I've been able to confirm this by running a query on another page that confirms that the user IsAdmin is 0.

Comment: you are not checking if 2 values are equal you are assigning a value

Comment: As others already mention. Check your code. The If statement is making an assignment.

Comment: Yeah! Very basic PHP! Sorry! Thank s for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a variable comparison. You have an assignment operator in your code.[Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)
Use the

```
if (!auth()->user()->IsAdmin){
    abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
}else{
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have known this!